# Why is state being lost in my app when passed via history.push()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've created the following very simple React app to simulate the behavior I'm seeing in my production app.

Root component:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  RouteComponentProps,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./home";
import { SubRoute } from "./sub-route";

export default function Root(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Home {...props} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/sub-route" exact>
          <SubRoute />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Home component:

```
import { LocationDescriptor } from "history";
import * as React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { TestLocationState } from "./sub-route";

export const Home = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const location: LocationDescriptor<TestLocationState> = {
            pathname: "/sub-route",
            state: {
              name: "STATE PAYLOAD",
            },
          };
          history.push(location);
        }}
      >
        Pass state to sub route
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

SubRoute component:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export type TestLocationState = {
  name: string;
};

export const SubRoute = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation<TestLocationState | undefined>();
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Sub Route</h1>
      <div>state: {JSON.stringify(state)}</div>
    </>
  );
};
```

In the dummy app, when I click the button in the Home component which calls `history.push()`, passing a location object with a `state` property, the `state` is not only successfully passed to the SubRoute component, but if I refresh or hard refresh, the state value is still available.

In my production app (a completely separate app that includes the above in addition to, of course a lot of other stuff), state is successfully passed to the SubRoute component, but it is **not** retained upon refresh.  It is `undefined`.

I'm very confused as to what could be causing different behavior in my production app versus my test app.  Is it a React Router thing?  Thoughts?

Comment: Your route would be getting modified in prod. I've seen some people use `<a href="#"...` and facing this issue as well.

Comment: What's your react and react-router-dom version?

Comment: @TopW3 react@17.0.2, react-dom@17.0.2, react-router-dom@5.2.0

Comment: I'm of the same version, and it works fine. will you share your project thru sandbox?

Comment: @TopW3 I can't share the prod repo. Only the simple repro repo where I'm not seeing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that another developer on the team had added this line of code in part of the application that was wiping out the state:

https://github.com/preactjs/preact-router#redirects